# Read data from smart card (eVRC) from an application running on the web server

Tags: php, pcsc

I have a web application in PHP that runs on a virtual server at a hosting provider.

I need to read the data from the card reader into the application (via USB using PHP extension `PC/SC`) and save it on the server (into MySQL).

First I built the app locally (I do development on XAMPP where I added `php_pcsc.dll` from `https://pecl.php.net/package/pcsc`). I created a program that reads data from a card.

But now I have a problem how to make this work on the server.

1. The provider does not want me to install the PC/SC php extension on the server, as it is not part of the Linux/Unix distribution.
2. Even if I managed to install the extension, I still cannot connect to the user's PC from the application on the server to read the data from the card via his USB.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks a lot for any idea.